# custom object powershell multiple items

Tags: powershell

I have this code wich work great for only one item
if I add a new item it just delete the older one

I've tried many way but I can't find how to do this
can you help me?

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$HostName = $env:computername
$DateNow = Get-Date -format d

$WebServerEngine_MajorVersion = get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\  | foreach >{$_.MajorVersion}
$WebServerEngine_MinorVersion = get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\  | foreach {$_.MinorVersion}
$IIS_Version = [string]$WebServerEngine_MajorVersion + "." + [string]$WebServerEngine_MinorVersion

$Webs = Get-Website | select name

if ($Webs) {
    ForEach ($Web in $Webs) {
    $InfoServer = new-object psobject
    $InfoServer | add-member noteproperty HostName $HostName
    $InfoServer | add-member noteproperty Date_report $DateNow
    $InfoServer | add-member noteproperty IIS_Version $IIS_Version
    $InfoServer | add-member noteproperty SiteName $Web.name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the $InfoServer object on each iteration through the loop. Try adding a Write-Output $InfoServer command at the end of the loop. This will send the data back out to the pipeline. Try this:

```
if ($Webs) {
    ForEach ($Web in $Webs) {
        $InfoServer = new-object psobject
        $InfoServer | add-member noteproperty HostName $HostName
        $InfoServer | add-member noteproperty Date_report $DateNow
        $InfoServer | add-member noteproperty IIS_Version $IIS_Version$InfoServer | add-member noteproperty SiteName $Web.name
        Write-Output $InfoServer
    }
}
```

Comment: the output is perfect but I need to reuse the output not only write it on screen